# How to skip elements where value of object is present in array?

Tags: javascript

Here is a functon that creates a new object filtered the object:

```
function filterErrors(errors: any) {
    const obj:any = {};
    const words = [
      'Unknown format',
      'There is no number',
    ] as string[];

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(errors)) {
      const filtered = (value as string[]).filter(
        (item: string) => !words.includes(item)
      );

      if (filtered.length > 0) {
        obj[key] = filtered;
      }
    }

    return obj;
  }


let errors = {
    "1": ["'D54'. Unknown format."],
    "2": ["'K53'. There is no number."]
}

console.log(filterErrors(errors));
```

As result I need to get an object where values are not presenetd in `words`. But now I got all data.

Comment: No, I need to find a part of word so `'Unknown format'` shoul skip elemen `'D54'. Unknown format.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this

```js
const filterErrors = (errors) => {
  
    const words = [
      'Unknown format',
      'There is no number',
    ] 

   return Object.entries(errors).reduce((res, [k, err]) => {
    const filtered = err.filter(error => !words.some(w => error.includes(w)))
    if(filtered.length > 0){
      res[k] = filtered
    }
    return res
   }, {})
  }


let errors = {
    "1": ["'D54'. Unknown format."],
    "2": ["'K53'. There is no number."],
    "3": ["'E42'. Another error."],
}

console.log(filterErrors(errors));
```

Comment: Your answer seems more elegant and I upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

You code seems to be `TypeScript` and I convert it to `JavaScript` and provide a solution for you

```js
function filterErrors(errors ) {
    const obj= {};
    const words = [
      'Unknown format',
      'There is no number'
    ];
    
    let keys = Object.keys(errors)
    keys.forEach(k => {
      let contains = false
      for(let w of words){
        if(errors[k][0].includes(w)){
          contains = true;
          break;
        }
      } 
      if(!contains){
       obj[k] = errors[k]
      }
    })

    return obj;
  }


let errors = {
    "1": ["'D54'. Unknown format."],
    "2": ["'K53'. There is no number."],
    "3": ["'K54'. Test Data"]
}

console.log(filterErrors(errors));
```